# Is there any difference between "What are you doing here" and "What are you doing OUT here"?

Tags: expressions

A friend of mine asked me that question and I have no clue, nor could I google it myself. So now I am wondering, what the actual difference is as it has always seemed to me that there is none.

Edit: it is here, not there in the phrase

Edit: the context is the cartoon, where the kid is standing outside the house and the grandpa opens the door and asks him "What are you doing out here"

Comment: The second one implies that you're doing something outside, the first doesn't.

Comment: @KillingTime so does that mean, that if I am asking someone standing outside "What are you doing there?", that is not an entirely correct way to ask?

Comment: Without further context, this is probably the 'out there in the big wide world', perhaps with an implied 'cruel' at the present time (2020). It's a metaphor, 'out' being the opposite of 'in my warm safe home' / 'hearth and home' [for which [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hearth+and+home) has 'home and its comforts']

Comment: I made a mistake, it is not there, it is here in the phrase

Comment: The grandpa is surprised that the child is out of doors, that's all.

Comment: some locations in space....out here, out there, in here, in there, up here, up there, not to mention **around here or there**....:) (useful idiomatic usages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a context to anchor the differences between the two questions.

In the game of baseball, occasionally the coach of the defensive team walks out to the pitcher's mound to consult with the pitcher. Perhaps the pitcher needs a little encouragement, or perhaps the coach feels he should be pulled out of the game and replaced with a relief pitcher.

The pitcher would not likely ask the coach either question--What are you doing here? or What are you doing out here? If, however, the coach decided to have a brief discussion with the left fielder, when they come face to face, the left fielder might very well ask the coach, "What are you doing out here?"

In this scenario, the word *out* functions as an adverb that modifies or gives more information about the gerund *doing*. *Out* can modify other verbs in different ways, such as in the sentence, "He pitched out his worn-out running shoes."

If the guy doing the pitching was angry with someone and picked up the nearest item to throw at him or her, you could then say, "He pitched his running shoes at Teddy (or Suzy)."

In short, the word *out* opens up the context a bit by giving the sentence a little more information. True enough, the word *pitched* can have more than one meaning, and it does not need an adverb. Idiomatically, however, "to pitch out" something generally means to throw something in the trash, usually because it no longer serves its purpose as well as something that is in better shape, newer, or perhaps even more attractive.